# Contador de pontos, Android Studio/Java

Tags: java, android-studio

Fiz um joguinho de Jokenpo no Android Studio (funciona normal), porém, não estou conseguindo contar os pontos (vitórias, empates e derrotas).
A parte do "contador" de pontos que está me confundindo e me travando.
"Acredito que tenha que criar os objetos: vitória, empate e derrota... Acredito que tenha que inicializar eles com o valor 0... Mas eu me perco nessa parte (criar, instanciar, etc)... E por fim, imagino que preciso colocar o contador dentro do meu if, else if e else, para toda vez que entrar na condição correta, somar os pontos e mudar o valor na tela (contando os pontos).
Alguém me ajuda, por favor ?
Segue meu código abaixo:

package com.example.joken;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.SyncStatusObserver;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

//criando método para elemento pedra
public void selecionandoPedra(View view) {
    this.opcaoSelecionada("PEDRA");
}

//criando método para elemento papel
public void selecionandoPapel(View view) {
    this.opcaoSelecionada("PAPEL");
}

//criando método para elemento tesoura
public void selecionandoTesoura(View view) {
    this.opcaoSelecionada("TESOURA");
}

//criando método usuário vs máquina
public void opcaoSelecionada(String escolhaUsuario) {
    //testando o clique dos botões
    //System.out.println("item que selecionei: " + escolhaUsuario);

    
    ImageView imagemResultado = findViewById(R.id.img_oponente);
    TextView textoResultado = findViewById(R.id.txt_resultado);
    
    //criando objetos para contabilizar os pontos
    TextView contadorVitorias = findViewById(R.id.txt_vitoria);
    TextView contadorEmpate = findViewById(R.id.txt_empate);
    TextView contadorDerrotas = findViewById(R.id.txt_derrota);

    //criando objeto e posições do seu array
    int posicoes = new Random().nextInt(3);//0, 1, 2
    String[] opcoes = {"PEDRA", "PAPEL", "TESOURA"};
    String escolhaOponente = opcoes[posicoes];

    //testando a jogada do oponente (aleatório)
    //System.out.println("item que o oponente escolheu rendomicamente: " + escolhaOponente);

    switch (escolhaOponente) {
        case "PEDRA":
            imagemResultado.setImageResource(R.drawable.img_pedra);
            break;

        case "PAPEL":
            imagemResultado.setImageResource(R.drawable.img_papel);
            break;

        case "TESOURA":
            imagemResultado.setImageResource(R.drawable.img_tesoura);
            break;
    }


    if (escolhaUsuario == "PEDRA" && escolhaOponente == "TESOURA" ||
            escolhaUsuario == "PAPEL" && escolhaOponente == "PEDRA" ||
            escolhaUsuario == "TESOURA" && escolhaOponente == "PAPEL") {
        textoResultado.setText("VOCÊ VENCEU !!!\nPARABÉNS !!!\nUHUUUUUUUUUU");
    } else if (escolhaUsuario == "PEDRA" && escolhaOponente == "PEDRA" ||
            escolhaUsuario == "PAPEL" && escolhaOponente == "PAPEL" ||
            escolhaUsuario == "TESOURA" && escolhaOponente == "TESOURA") {
        textoResultado.setText("EMPATOU !!!");
    } else {
        textoResultado.setText("VOCÊ PERDEU !!!\nHAHAHAHA" +
                "\nBEM FEITO, RECEEEEEEEEBA\nPERDEDOR !!!\nLOOOOOOSER");
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score -2):

Você poderia fazer assim:

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   int empapates = 0;
   int vitorias = 0;
   int derrotas = 0;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       TextView edtResultadoVitoria =  (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_vitoria);
       TextView edtResultadoDerrota =  (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_derrota);
       TextView edtResultadoEmpate =  (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_empate);

   }


   // criando método para elemento pedra
   public void selecionandoPedra(View view) {
       this.opcaoSelecionada("PEDRA");
   }

   // criando método para elemento papel
   public void selecionandoPapel(View view) {
       this.opcaoSelecionada("PAPEL");
   }

   // criando método para elemento tesoura
   public void selecionandoTesoura(View view) {
       this.opcaoSelecionada("TESOURA");
   }

   // criando método usuário vs máquina
   public void opcaoSelecionada(String escolhaUsuario) {
       // testando o clique dos botões
       // System.out.println("item que selecionei: " + escolhaUsuario);


       ImageView imagemResultado = findViewById(R.id.img_oponente);
       TextView textoResultado = findViewById(R.id.txt_resultado);
       
       TextView contadorVitorias = findViewById(R.id.txt_vitoria);
       TextView contadorEmpate = findViewById(R.id.txt_empate);
       TextView contadorDerrotas = findViewById(R.id.txt_derrota);



       // criando objeto e posições do seu array
       int posicoes = new Random().nextInt(3);// 0, 1, 2
       String[] opcoes = { "PEDRA", "PAPEL", "TESOURA" };
       String escolhaOponente = opcoes[posicoes];

       // testando a jogada do oponente (aleatório)
       // System.out.println("item que o oponente escolheu rendomicamente: " +
       // escolhaOponente);

       switch (escolhaOponente) {
           case "PEDRA":
               imagemResultado.setImageResource(R.drawable.img_pedra);
               break;

           case "PAPEL":
               imagemResultado.setImageResource(R.drawable.img_papel);
               break;

           case "TESOURA":
               imagemResultado.setImageResource(R.drawable.img_tesoura);
               break;
       }

       if (escolhaUsuario == "PEDRA" && escolhaOponente == "TESOURA"
               || escolhaUsuario == "PAPEL" && escolhaOponente == "PEDRA"
               || escolhaUsuario == "TESOURA" && escolhaOponente == "PAPEL") {

           vitorias++;
           contadorVitorias.setText(vitorias);
           textoResultado.setText("VOCÊ VENCEU !!!\nPARABÉNS !!!\nUHUUUUUUUUUU");

       } else if (escolhaUsuario == "PEDRA" && escolhaOponente == "PEDRA"
               || escolhaUsuario == "PAPEL" && escolhaOponente == "PAPEL"
               || escolhaUsuario == "TESOURA" && escolhaOponente == "TESOURA") {
           empapates++;
           textoResultado.setText("EMPATOU !!!");
           contadorEmpate.setText(empapates);
       } else {
           textoResultado .setText("VOCÊ PERDEU !!!\nHAHAHAHA" + "\nBEM FEITO, RECEEEEEEEEBA\nPERDEDOR !!!\nLOOOOOOSER");
           derrotas++;
           contadorDerrotas.setText(derrotas);

       }

   }

}
```

Eu criei variáveis que são iniciadas com valor 0 e vão ser incrementas quanto as condições do if fossem atendidas, se for empate incrementa o empate, se for derrota incrementa a derrota e no caso da vitória incrementa a vitória depois seta o valor da variável no Edit Text.

Eu sugiro vc colocar as algumas funcionalidades em classe separadas, ajuda na manutenção e na organização ex: colocar uma classe para o usuário onde ficaria a escolha dele (tesoura, papel ou pedra) e outra onde ficaria a escolha da maquinha e na main você deixaria a logica para saber quem foi o vencedor e o placar, Mas isso é só uma sugestão.

Espero ter ajudado! ;)